# Were is getRotationMatrixFromVector in Monodroid?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I can't fing this method in any version of Mono.Android.dll...

Comment: While I understand there was an answered posted this question itself is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a static method

```
SensorManager.GetRotationMatrixFromVector(float[], float[])
```

Namespace: Android.Hardware.

It works since API Level 9.